# How to Documents.add inside of my current working directory VBA MSWord

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
Set myCopy = Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName) ActiveDocument.Path
And...
Set myCopy = Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName) & ActiveDocument.Path
```

It's not working because I cannot figure out the syntax. Could anyone help me out?

Also, I do NOT have access to the Default Documents folder on Windows. So if I create a copied document, it will by default, create it inside of the Documents folder.

Proof I've used to determine this is by doing:

```
Set myCopy = Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName)
myCopy.SaveAs2 (ActiveDocument.Path & docName)
```

This shows me that it's populated inside of the Default Folder which I cannot access and by result, I cannot invoke this command:

```
myCopy.SaveAs2 (".\Payload\" & docName)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For clarification, I cannot use relative pathing once the copied document is already located in another directory than my original working directory. I need to make this code relative.

Comment: VBA does not use relative paths. You always need to specify the full path. As far as figuring out syntax, that's what the F1 button is for.

Answer (score 0):

Documents.Add does not take a path variable - you can only add a path when saving. Hence, for example:

```
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument
Set DocTgt = Documents.Add(DocSrc.Fullname)
DocTgt.SaveAs FileName:=DocSrc.Path & "\" & DocName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```